# Finding Total of Multiple Hands in Blackjack

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple hands of a Blackjack game.

ex.

```
Player 1 = ['AD', 'AS']
Player 2 = ['6C', '3D']
Player 3 = ['TD', 'AH']
```

And I'm trying to get the value of each hand by referencing it to a deck value dictionary:

```
deckValue = {'AH':11, '2H':2,'3H':3, '4H':4, '5H':5, '6H': 6, '7H': 7, '8H':8, 
         '9H':9, 'TH':10, 'JH':10, 'QH':10, 'KH':10, 'AC':11, '2C':2,'3C':3,
         '4C':4, '5C':5, '6C':6,'7C': 7, '8C':8, '9C':9, 'TC':10, 'JC':10, 
         'QC':10, 'KC':10, 'AS':11, '2S':2,'3S':3, '4S':4, '5S':5, '6S': 6, 
         '7S': 7, '8S':8, '9S':9, 'TS':10, 'JS':10, 'QS':10, 'KS':10, 
         'AD':11, '2D':2,'3D':3, '4D':4, '5D':5, '6D': 6, '7D': 7, '8D':8, 
         '9D':9, 'TD':10, 'JD':10, 'QD':10, 'KD':10}
```

Finding a value in a dictionary can be achieved with the

deckvalue.get(key)

or

deckvalue[key]

Where key would be the string in each hand ex. deckvalue.get('AH') = 11

To achieve what I'm trying to do, I'm using a for loop to go through each hand and find the total value.

```
def calculate_hand(pHands):
    # What I have so far
    total = 0
    for i in pHands:
        deckValue.get(pHands[i][0])
        deckValue.get(pHands[i][1])
        total = #value of 0 + value of 1 
return
```

Where pHands is:

```
pHands = [['AD', 'AS'], ['6C', '3D'], ['TD', 'AH']]
```

But I'm getting a 'list indices must be integers, not list' error

I'm new to Python, so I have no clue what this is (but it's probably due to the pHands containing str elements not int elements).

How could I get individual totals for each hand?

eg.

```
pHands[0] = 22
pHands[1] = 9
pHands[2] = 21
```

Would I have to assign a new variable to save each hands total to?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: If you're iterating over a list, you don't get indices, but actually the list elements.

Comment: try printing `i` inside your loop ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're iterating over a list, you don't get indices, but actually the list elements. Better:

```
def calculate_hand(pHands):
    # What I have so far
    values = []
    for (card1, card2) in pHands:
        total = deckValue.get(card1) + deckValue.get(card2)
        values.append(total)
    return values
```

Also, there's a more concise way to get the value of a card:

```
def getvalue(card):
    val = card[0]
    return 11 if val=="A" else 10 if val in "TQKJ" else int(val)
```

If you have a function like that, you can actually write the whole `calculate_hand` function in single list comprehension:

```
def calculate_hand(pHands):
    return [getvalue(card1) + getvalue(card2) for (card1, card2) in pHands]
```

Comment: this will get the total of every hand combined, not the individual total of each hand separately

Comment: @depperm Ah, I see, I thought that was the goal. Give me a second.